# HTML Security Concepts for class

Tags: html

SO I teach an HTML programming class. We learn all the standard HTML tags that one would use. Was looking through the textbook and I noticed there is not much emphasis in terms of security. So far the only thing I can think of in terms of security is to make sure you host your images and scripts on your servers. What other security measures should I teach them? Remember, they only know HTML - nothing else.

Comment: This kind of polls are better suited for forums. You cannot really teach people security from just one technology (if HTML can be called as such). Social engineering (pages that looks like your bankers site), there are many other options that are not directly related to the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security is not normally achieved through HTML. HTML is only designed as a markup language to display data.. In web development it is known as an exclusively front end language.

HTML is passed to the client completely. You should never hide data in HTML or java script. The user can see your code by using the development tools.

If you want to teach your students about web security I would start looking into PHP, asp.net, jsp and ruby languages HTML poses almost no threat because its role is to format and display information. Processing and data retrieval is done by the more advanced back end languages.

I hate to point this out, but HTML is not a programing language. It is simply markup.

Comment: Thank you, makes alot of sense. I'll be sure to explain these concepts to my students. (I am teaching HTML at a summer camp, if you are wondering.)

Comment: HTML is a great way to introduce students to web development. Its extremely simple, but at the end of the day no matter what language you use, the browser will only ever receive HTML/Javascript. Message me if you have anymore questions, I do ASP.NET web development for a university :).

Answer (score 1):

HTML isn't a programming language; there is practically nothing to secure. You've already covered everything with "Don't load untrusted resources".